# Sending personalized Google app-script emails led to my email getting disabled

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I am using Google app-scripts to send out personalized emails to notify clients of COVID19 related changes to their programs. The script read in different parameters which required us to not use Google Groups.

After sending out my messages, I received a disabled notification a few days after saying that it was disabled for spam - luckily I was able to reactive my account. After researching, I realized that part of the issue might be the quota and I definitely surpassed the 1500 email quota set by Gmail. Is this why the account was disabled or was there another reason?

I was thinking of splitting up the emails (~1600) across 10 users moving forward to help balance out the quantity, would this help?

Comment: If you surpasses any of the quota limits, you will receive a respective [exception message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages). The fact that your emails have been classified as spam is not related to surpassing Apps Script / Gmail quota, but rather that it can seem suspicious if somebody send a huge amount of emails in a short time, especially if the emails all have the same subject, and even more if the subject contains keywords that might be classified as spam. Sending the emails over a longer time period might help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some users might have "reported" your email to google. Such reporting will speed up the process of disabling your google account.